# My codes using 'pandas.dataframe.nlargest()' returns a memory error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack

I'm trying to find top n values from my pandas dataframe.
(raw data is around 2000*2000 idx*column size)

It is returning Memory Error.

Not even sure what exactly my error means.
Tried to google it but couldn't find same issue so far

```
X = int(input())
TopX = CorrVal.stack().nlargest(X)
```

(CorrVal data is correlation value between item sales amount)
So I want to have top n largest values of correlation

```
item01 item02 0.744
item05 item04 0.689
item04 item03 0.554
...    ...    ...
```

Error Codes below

```
TopX = CorrVal.stack().nlargest(X)
```

> File
>   "C:\Users\2F4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 3120, in nlargest
>       return algorithms.SelectNSeries(self, n=n, keep=keep).nlargest()   File
>   "C:\Users\2F4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py",
>   line 1058, in nlargest
>       return self.compute('nlargest')   File "C:\Users\2F4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py",
>   line 1124, in compute
>       kth_val = algos.kth_smallest(arr.copy(), n - 1) MemoryError

What kind of functions or tools can i use solve this problem?

Comment: Try using `modin` for faster pandas operation!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal thank you for the comment. but  i need to solve the error instead of make it faster. will modin work?

Comment: Yes it will..bcoz your error is coming because it is talking too much time and hence is unable to allocate that much memory!! Can't recreate this at my end because I dont have your file!!